# Easiest way to get data from single file and inject into 4 HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I have a static web page for a restaurant. The menu changes twice a year. Site is bi-lingual.

I want to know what would you recommend to achieve such effect -
 I want to change one (*not four like now*) file (*could be text, JSON, whatever*) and see results on those pages - two pages in one language should be updated, and two in the other. I don't want to mess with CMS of any kind (*I'm a front-end developer and don't want to get into SQLs/PHP and such*). I thought maybe jQuery or AngularJS could do that? But how?

The file itself could be something like that:

```
en_Tea | de_Tea
en_sandwich | de_sandwich
en_pizza | de_pizza
```

or JSON of some kind...

Comment: You're a front end developer asking how to use jQuery or Angular to build a website to display some simple data that changes twice a year?   To sum it up, yes Angular would be overkill as would React, Redux and most other client side tools.  Why not just HTML/CSS and jQuery?

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm very lazy and this is a side-side project for me, I want to keep maintenance as minimum as possible, but... At the beginning I had even more work to do, because those 4 pages were different in style, now I've managed to keep this "menu" simple as possible (divs with clean "p" inside) and styling is - as it should be - in a more "exterior" way (I hope you know what I mean) - and by creating this clean-div-p skeleton I can copy-paste the contents in two languages (still have to edit 4 files, not 1). Now I'm trying to simplify the editing of this menu and experiment as well

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like add a stub .js file that gets imported to your full page files. In the stub file, you could simply have a function that builds a constant array with whatever values you like. The calling portions of your code could then use the values however they would like.

Answer (score 0):

[Check jQuery Ajax functions & methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Some you could use:

- `$.ajax()` - the most configurable one.
- `.load()` - adds functionality which allows you to define where in the document the returned data is to be inserted.
- `$.get()` - abstracts some of the configurations away, setting reasonable default values for what it hides from you.

  Most are shorthands for `$.ajax()`

You can make these requests when certain elements are clicked and bring/replace specific content without having to refresh the whole page.